# Authenticate :user default action on sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, sidekiq

Is it possible to change the default redirect to `main_app.root_path` when mounting `sidekiq` ?

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.has_role? :admin } do      
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/dashboard' 
end
```

When I am logged with an another role than admin, and go to `/dashboard`, I got `404`, which is nice.

But when I am not connected at all, I'm redirected to `main_app.root_path` but I want to get `404` also.

Cheers, Ben

Comment: I don't think there is any clean way to do this Ben; lets see if any body answers

Comment: Well I agree with you illusionist :/ Still looking on it but couldn't find a way yes